# How to use Past Perfect correctly in Reported Speech?

Tags: reported-speech

Is the below sentence construction is correct using had been?

"The homemaker was returning after dropping Siddhesh to school when the bridge had collapsed."

This sentence construction seems awkward to me because by reading this I can imagine that when she returned to the bridge after dropping his son to school the bridge had already collapsed. Actually She was on the bridge when it collapsed and because of it she died in that accident. Please correct the sentence if wrong.

Refer below news artical for details

https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/city/mumbai/gokhale-bridge-collapse-after-housewife-52-year-old-ca-dies/articleshow/65190895.cms

Answer (score 1):

Using past perfect (**had + [past participle]**) makes the sentence sound contrived and akward indeed.

Try using past simple instead:

> The homemaker was returning after dropping Siddhesh off to school when the bridge collapsed.

If you do feel the need to use past perfect in that sentence, it could be used in the first part.

> The homemaker had dropped Siddhesh off to school and was returning when the bridge collapsed.

But for clarification you might want to state that she was on the bridge as it happened.

> The homemaker had dropped Siddhesh off to school and was returning when the bridge she was on collapsed.